# Using PowerShell DataTable to import data into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I need to import a `.csv` file with 350 columns into a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

Surfing the internet I came up with a function called `Out-DataTable` from Chad Miller: [link to script on Technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/4208a159-a52e-4b99-83d4-8048468d29dd)

I have used this to complete the PowerShell script as follows:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
$logNaam=MylogFileName
TRY
{
    $ConnectionString = "Data Source=mySQLServer; Initial Catalog=MyDB; Trusted_Connection=True;";
    . ".\Out-DataTable.ps1"

    $csvDataTable = Import-CSV -Path "MyCSV_FileAndPath" | Out-DataTable
    $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $ConnectionString
    $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "to_MyTableName"
    $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($csvDataTable)
}
  Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
      "Error: Job starten lukt niet : ($ErrorMessage) " | out-file $logNaam -append
        "Error: Job starten lukt niet : ($FailedItem) " | out-file $logNaam -append
}
Finally
{}

#----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Running this code in the PowerShell command prompt, I get this error:

> Unexpected token 'data' in expression or statement.
>   At .\MyScript.ps1:20 char:27
>   +     $ConnectionString = "Data <<<<  Source=MySQLServer; Initial Catalog=MyDB
>       ; Trusted_Connection=True;";
>   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (data:String) [], ParseException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

I'm stuck with this and have no clue where to start. Changing `Data Source=MySQLServer` to `Server=MySQLServer` does not solve it. The message only changed pointing to the position following MySQLServer<<<.

Also adding the Windows server-name to it (`MyWinServer\MySQLServer`) did not help, either.

Any advise, directions, explanation or help to code this script would by much appreciated.

Comment: I just tried your script, in Connection string I put this: `$ConnectionString = "Data Source=SERVER\INSTANCE ;Database=MYDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"` and I catch error on `$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($csvDataTable)` because I don't have a table I have specified on my SQL Server side.

Comment: @gofr1 thanks for your assistance. Can you please explain if you make use of the function `Out-DataTable`?

Comment: My pleasure! Yes, it works fine, but I had to create table to store data manually.

Comment: @gofr1 Okay. It works for me only when the columns of the receiving table all are `varchar` tables. That is a problem because I need to perform calculations on the results.

Comment: As I see from the code of this script, it tries to determine datatype of value, if `Get-Type` returns array - it assign `String `datatype to this value. Also I bet that `Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` is similar to `BULK INSERT` in SQL Server, that means problems with decimal and numeric datatypes (they must be converted into real or float [here is some info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library)/ms188365.aspx#Anchor_3).

Comment: Can you elaborate if this csv will be loaded one time or it will be permanent process (every day f.e.) Is the structure of this csv determined (columns and there datatypes) or will be dynamic?

Comment: @gofr1 ThX for your assistance. It looks like a logical explanation. Can you please edit the link you suggested because it doesn't lead me to the page you intended.

Comment: @gofr1 it will be a daily process and the format of the csv file is determined.

Comment: Hi! I can make it tomorrow, as soon as I can.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx#Anchor_3 this was the link I posted incomments

Comment: If CSV has some determined structure and you need it daily - I suggest you to use SSIS package and run it through job.